# SQL Server : want a column to be nullable only for existing and newly created rows

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Is it possible to make a column that can only be `NULL` from the beginning, but once it has been set to a non-null value then it can never be reset to `NULL`?

I'm guessing it might be possible with an update constraint using both the inserted and deleted table, but that seems somewhat complicated given the goal of the task.

Bonus question: Since it doesn't seem easy to do this, is this a sign of bad design (on the part of us / `SQL Server`)?

Comment: In which RDBMS? MSSQL or ther DBMS?

Comment: @Selva -TS:MSSQL though I would be curious to know if other DBMS's handle this scenario more cleanly.

Comment: Wouldn't you just want to constrain the value to never be null from the updating system, i.e. UI or procedures?

Comment: You can do this with a trigger or a constraint that uses a user-defined function.  As for the question of whether this is good or bad, you would need to explain in more detail what you are modeling.  I would suggest that you ask another question, explaining the data being modeled, and asking how you can enforce such a constraint.

Comment: @BrianAtkins: You are probably right that that would be easiest, but I would basically have to ensure that there is only one way of updating this column and that way gets the null check.  I'm never quite sure if these things should be enforced at the lowest level (the DB) or the easier level (the code.)

Answer (score 1):

Since you're allowing the filed to be NULL when the ROW is Inserted, you'll have to use a Trigger for Update

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1 ON table1
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN 
     SET NOCOUNT ON
     DECLARE @field1 VARCAHR(MAX)
     select @field1 = field1 FROM INSERTED

     IF @field1 is NULL
     BEGIN
         RAISERROR('A NULL Values are not allowed', 15, 1)
         ROLLBACK
     END
END
```

Comment: Can you add solution for multiinsert?

Comment: The trigger should fire with every row inserted.  The drawback is you could take a performance hit when inserting numerous rows

Comment: I mean when you are inserting bulk not row by row. In this case your trigger will pick random row and wont look for others. Insert into table select * from(select 1 union select 2 union select 3). you are inserting 3 rows at once

Comment: To do that you could reject the whole update by using  a `select count(*) where field1 is null from INSTERTED`.  and test for a count of greater than zero. If you wanted to just kick out the NULL rows you would have to use a [Coursor] (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx)

Comment: @jradich1234: I think that would work.  But I don't think I'd want to kick out the NULL rows because I feel like that wouldn't be transactional or it would be some form of silent erroring.

Answer (score 1):

"Allowing null value in a column initially, but once set to non null value, it must not allow null value for the same row"

This is clearly a business logic. It must be handled in controller part of MVC. Trying to handle it in database layer will break the MVC principle, and thus is a bad design.

If you still want to handle it in DBMS, then, as suggested in other answers, you can use triggers.

Comment: How do you know that OP uses MVC?

Comment: +1 because it sounds like you know what you're talking about, although I'm not quite sure how you arrove at the business layer conclusion. @GiorgiNakeuri: It just so happens that I don't use MVC.

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri Even if OP isn't using MVC, but the correct approach is, still, to use MVC, especially in those applications in which databases are involved.

Comment: @user420667: Why do you want the column to allow null initially, and once a non null value is inserted, then null is not allowed? Why do you want this?

Comment: @djaqeel: I guess you're right.  This is not something *I* decided but something that was told to me to be done.

Comment: @djaqeel: Basically once it's not null, we want the option to make it null go away... so maybe that's more of the V part.

Answer (score 1):

The trigger may look like this. You join `INSERTED` on `DELETED` to check **if column was `NOT NULL` and became `NULL`**:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trCheckForNulls ON SomeTable
AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN 
     IF UPDATE(SomeColumn)
     BEGIN     
          IF EXISTS(
                     SELECT * FROM INSERTED i
                     JOIN DELETED d ON i.PK = d.PK
                     WHERE d.SomeColumn IS NOT NULL AND i.SomeColumn IS NULL)
          BEGIN
              RAISERROR('SomeError', 16, 1)
              ROLLBACK
          END
     END
END
```